# Log4j Logger and concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton, log4j

Is it okay to have a org.apache.log4j.Logger field in a singleton class?
Could be any concurrency issues because of sharing it among multiple threads?

Comment: Normally you would create a singleton logger per class, in the class to be logged.  This allows you to turn logging on and off for different classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there'll be no problems because it's thread-safe (i.e. it won't break if multiple threads are accessing it at the same time).

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a1.7

Answer (score 1):

No, a Logger object can be used by multiple threads, did you face any issues?